# How to write a unique value which is there in the 2 lists in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, unique, display

```
List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list1.add(1);
list1.add(2);
list1.add(3);
list1.add(4);
List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list2.add(1);
list2.add(2);
list2.add(3);
list2.add(4);
list2.add(5);
```

In the above code, I have to compare and write unique value which is present in the list2.
Here I have to get the output as 5 bcz which is unique as it is not present in the list1.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to find everything that is only in list 2:

```
    List<Integer> uniqueItems = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int item : list2) {
        if (!list1.contains(item)) {
            uniqueItems.add(item);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(uniqueItems);
```

Comment: Thank you everyone who answered. As of now I am going with @David Wright ans. Thanks mate.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this create a copy of List2. Let's say it's diffList.
And then remove those duplicates using removeAll method.

```
    List<Integer> diffList = new ArrayList<Integer>(list2);//create Copy of list2
    diffList.removeAll(list1);//remove duplicates using list1
    for(int aa : diffList)
        System.out.println(aa);
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is just one single extra value in List2, it is a known problem:

```
List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
list1.add(1);
list1.add(3);
list1.add(2);
list1.add(4);
list1.add(2);
List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
list2.add(1);
list2.add(2);
list1.add(2);
list2.add(3);
list2.add(4);
list2.add(5);

int vr = 0;
for (Integer v: list1) {
    vr ^= v;
}
for (Integer v: list2) {
    vr ^= v;
}
System.out.println("The result is: " + vr);
```

Otherwise Set instead of List would be more suitable (if all elements are different).

There is one simple solution (for List costly) using:

```
list2.removeAll(list1)
```

If the lists are sorted there again is a better solution.